# Build path with as many fields without reaching max_length

Tags: python

I have a few fields like title, date, actors, tags. I want to make a function that gets the fields and creates a path below the length limit. Using up to 3 actors and as many tags, as it can.

```
d = {
    "title": "title",
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "performers": ["perf1", "perf2", "perf3", "perf4"],
    "studio": "studio",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
}

# The order in which the fields are added to the path
# The later will be discarded if the path is too long
order_fields = ["date", "performers", "studio", "tags"]
template = "{studio} {date} {performers} {title} {tags}"

def build_path(d: dict, template: str, order_fields: list, max_length: int = 255) -> str:
    for field in order_fields:
        if field not in d:
            continue
        if isinstance(d[field], list):
            d[field] = ", ".join(d[field])
        if len(template + d[field]) > max_length:
            break
        template = template.replace(f"{{{field}}}", d[field])
    for field in order_fields:
        template = template.replace(" {" + field + "}", "")
    return template

def test_build_path():
    global d, template, order_fields
    assert build_path(d, template, order_fields, max_length=5) == "title"
    assert build_path(d, template, order_fields, max_length=16) == "2020-01-01 title"
    assert build_path(d, template, order_fields, max_length=36) == "2020-01-01 perf1, perf2, perf3 title"
    assert build_path(d, template, order_fields, max_length=43) == "studio 2020-01-01 perf1, perf2, perf3 title"
    assert build_path(d, template, order_fields, max_length=48) == "studio 2020-01-01 perf1, perf2, perf3 title tag1"
    assert build_path(d, template, order_fields) == "studio 2020-01-01 perf1, perf2, perf3 title tag1, tag2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fixes your issue, but you could try

```
if len(path)   >=   max_length:
    return path
```

Then your returned path would never be longer than max_length.